# Typescript generated JavaScript has a function that is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, compiler-construction, typescript

This typescript:

```
export enum UID {
    FACTORY,
    ROBOT
}
```

compiles to this javascript:

```
(function (UID) {
    UID._map = [];
    UID._map[0] = "FACTORY";
    UID.FACTORY = 0;
    UID._map[1] = "ROBOT";
    UID.ROBOT = 1;
})(exports.UID || (exports.UID = {}));
var UID = exports.UID;
```

I have to admit that the code seems rather obscure to me but I trusted the tsc compiler to know what it's doing. Unfortunately the javascript can't be executed. nodejs complains that:

> (function (UID) {
>
> ^ TypeError: object is not a function
>
> ```
> at ...
> ```

What have I done wrong ?

UPDATE:
Matt B. has solved the problem. This is a known bug in the typescript compiler. tsc fails to insert semicolons after require statements, this can lead to strange errors. Manually adding the semicolons to my code solved the problem. Here's the link to the codeplex issue:
http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/364

**UPDATE 2:**
for those of you that experience the same error. You can insert the missing semicolons manually but that is not a very comfortable solution since you have to do this after every compilation. I noted that the problem only occurs with the enum. There are lots of other modules in the project and none of them have caused this error. Apparently a class definition is not "harmed" by the missing semicolons in front of it. Just move the definition of the enum behind one of your class definitions and the error should disappear. It's not sufficient to move the enum behind an interface since interfaces have no direct equivalent and are just deleted by the compiler

Comment: Is that the whole script?

Comment: That second `)` (in your error message) shouldn't be there: `(function (UID)) {`. The code portion works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/cRNeN/

Comment: That code works fine for me.

Comment: incorrect concatenation with another file?

Comment: The code in the error message is not the same as the code posted above it.  The error contains the double `)`, not the sample posted.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. In the error message there only one brace. I can't copy from the windows shell, so I typed it per hand

Comment: @Bergi no it's not the whole script. The module that exports the enum contains a few class definitions, too. The classes have members with this enum as their type, but otherwise they are independent. I don't think the rest of the file has anything to do with the error

Comment: @canon I don't know how you got this to work. But you've added one line to the fiddle: var exports= {}. That doesn't exist in the original

Comment: And it's not needed because you're in node.js so `exports` is already defined.

Comment: @lhk: Since the circumflex points to the start of the expression, it is very likely that the rest of the file is responsible for the error. Does it work without? Please post the whole thing, or the smallest snippet of it that shows the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is the same issue as described here -- which turned out to be due to a missing semicolon after a `require()` statement:

[Typescript generating javascript that doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203558/typescript-generating-javascript-that-doesnt-work/13203882#comment21512231_13203882)

Is there a line like this in another *compiled* file?

`var UID = require('UID')`

If so, try adding a semicolon at the end:

`var UID = require('UID');`

This appears to be a TypeScript bug; here's the bug report (vote it up!): http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/364

Comment: yes, that solved the problem. Thank you for your answer. I upvoted the issue on codeplex, too

Comment: In case others want to upvote the bug report as well, here's the link: http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/364

Comment: nice, Ill add the link to the question

Answer (score 0):

In your Javascript you should have something like

```
var exports = exports || {};
```

Before

```
(function (UID) {
    UID._map = [];
    UID._map[0] = "FACTORY";
    UID.FACTORY = 0;
    UID._map[1] = "ROBOT";
    UID.ROBOT = 1;
})(exports.UID || (exports.UID = {}));
var UID = exports.UID;
```

Comment: but the javascript was not generated by me. Does that mean that the typescript compiler is responsible for this error ?

Comment: The global `exports` reference is native to the Node.js environment and does not need to be declared.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and I have the same problem - I assume that the missing `exports` variables should be generated by the JavaScript code used to load the module when you do

```
import XXXX = module("XXXX");
```

that generates this JavaScript:

```
var XXXX = require("./XXXX")
```

and I think Matt B. is right and the problem there is the missing semi-colon after `require()`, that messes things up afterwards.

A fix is to place the enumeration declaration in a module:

```
module Test {

    export enum UID {
      FACTORY,
      ROBOT
    }

}
```

that generates:

```
var test;
(function (test) {
    (function (UID) {
        UID._map = [];
        UID._map[0] = "FACTORY";
        UID.FACTORY = 0;
        UID._map[1] = "ROBOT";
        UID.ROBOT = 1;
    })(test.UID || (test.UID = {}));
    var UID = test.UID;
})(test || (test = {}));
```

in this way the `exports` variable is no longer needed.